# Get table view cell index once a button is clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to select a cell in a table view and once I click on the "done" button in the navigation menu I want to `println()` the index of that row, eg 0, 1, 2 etc.

When you click on the "done" button a segue is fired and I want to catch the value in `prepareForSegue`

I can get the index when I click on a cell by using:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

and then inside that function:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: indexPath)
```

But how can I tweak it to work with:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do if Done is pressed and a row hasn't been selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `indexPathForSelectedRow` to get the indexPath in your button handler:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

If there is no selected row at the time the *Done* button is pressed, there will be no `indexPath` and the segue will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class wide variable and save the indexpath of a clicked selected cell to it every time the cell is selected. Then pass that value in prepare for segue. But know that you need a variable on your incoming view controller to receive the value you are passing.

so

```
var selectedRow
```

then inside

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

you can assign that variable the row number or any other value you might want to pass from that row.

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row
```

and finally when you click your done button, in prepare for segue you can capture the incoming view controller using segue.destinationViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "mySegue") {

        var nextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as nextViewControllerClass)
        nextViewController.receivingValueVariable = selectedRow
    }
}
```

dont forget to assign a variable to receive the value you are passing.

it could go something like this, int he class of your next view controller

```
class nextViewControllerClass {

    var receivingValueVariable:Int
```